# Aggregation on distinct values after substring() is used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a log collector app that collects app usage logs from multiple computers. The logs contain fields including "app" which is the path to an app and "seconds" which stores how long it was used.

My goal is to get the top 10 most used apps. Since I store app paths and not just app names, I use a substring function to extract app names. I use the following sql query:

```
SELECT substring(app from '[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$') as app,
sum(seconds) as sum
FROM tbl_logs_app_focus
GROUP BY app
ORDER BY sum DESC
NULLS LAST
LIMIT 10
```

This is an example result with this query:

```
**"app"                        "sum"**
"explorer.exe"                 551404.9595867295
"OneDrive.exe"                 510425.765499115
"putty.exe"                    272261.3288867716
"chrome.exe"                   160638.84143324356
"MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe"  92442.94607090577
"Code.exe"                     88504.6548490785
"MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe"  21666.859371185303
"chrome.exe"                   8569.392006158829
"vmware-vmrc.exe"              7976.217761993408
"pgAdmin4.exe"                 6493.827002130449
```

As you can notice, there are duplicates like "MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe". The reason why this happens is that the app names were extracted from logs of two different computers. And since the usernames of those computers were different, even though the app names were the same, the paths were different. Like this:

```
"C:\Users\<Example User 1>\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_MobaXterm_Portable_v22.1.zip\MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe"
"C:\Users\<Example User 2>\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_MobaXterm_Portable_v22.1.zip\MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe"
```

The current query displays the paths as file names but sums the seconds of distinct paths instead of distinct file names. How can I modify the query so it sums the distinct file names and doesn't cause duplicates?

Comment: can you share the input rows and output rows of different cases where you also have duplicates ? I would like to see at the original sample data

Comment: the example query won't return the  `MobaXterm_Personal_22.1.exe` twice since you are doing group by on the column `app`. it would actually add up  `92442.94607090577` and `21666.859371185303` and will not show two different rows

Comment: @trillion Turns out the problem was that the alias and the actual column name was the same but the group_by function was taking the column name. I changed the alias to app_name and used the group_by function with that which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the alias and the actual column name were the same but the group_by function was taking the column name. I changed the alias to app_name and used the group_by function with that which solved the problem.

Here's the correct query:

```
SELECT substring(app from '[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$') as app_name,
sum(seconds) as sum
FROM tbl_logs_app_focus
GROUP BY app_name
ORDER BY sum DESC
NULLS LAST
LIMIT 10
```